# Avoid needless SUBST /D when setting SUBST

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

How can one recode

```
subst P: /D
subst P: D:\mydir
```

such that a second run does not delete the drive needlessly i.e. if the drive is already subst-ed to this path?

The momentary removal of the drive interferes with an Explorer view that I have watching that drive.

Comment: Is it possible P: could be connected to a different path or is it just enough to check if P is connected (to any random path) and if not connect it to D:\mydir ?? The latter would be easy to do with an `IF NOT EXIST P:\NUL subst P: D:\mydir`

Comment: @Rik, thanks for the thought but I do need the full check. Leaving P: on a different path would be disastrous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you definitely need the full check that P: get redirected to D:\mydir

You could do it like this (save as a batch-file):

```
@echo off
subst | findstr /C:"P:\\: => D:\\MYDIR" 1> nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo. P-drive not mapped to D:\mydir
  echo. remapping P:\
  subst P: /D 1> nul
  subst P: D:\mydir
) else (
  echo. P-drive already mapped to D:\mydir
)
```

It checks (with command `subst` and `findstr`) if the `P:` is already mapped to `D:\mydir`.
(please note the **double** \ in the check with `findstr`)
(also please note that `subst` always returns the path in **all caps**)

- if `P:\: => D:\MYDIR` is not present in `subst` then we need to remap.
- The `subst P: /D 1> nul` deletes the current `P:`
  (and suppresses any error message in case `P:` was not mapped)
- Then with `subst P: D:\mydir` we map the drive
  (no error message should appear as we just deleted any P-mapping)
- You could delete the echo-lines if you don't want them

Please check your output of `subst` to see if it corresponds with the format i used here. So:
`P:\: => D:\MYDIR`
(if not, please adjust the batch-file accordingly)

**Edit:**
Here is a revised (and parameterized) version. You can call it like `remap P: D:\mydir`. The new version is case-insensitive. It adds the double \ to the `findstr` parameters. It checks beforehand if the directory exists (it may not contain a trailing slash).

```
@echo off
if "%2"=="" (
  echo. Call with: %0 drive: destination-direcory
  exit/b
)
if not exist "%2\." (
  echo. The destination directory does not exist
  exit/b
)
SET drive=%1\\
SET dest=%2
SET dest=%dest:\=\\%
subst | findstr /I /R /C:"^%drive%: => %dest%$" 1> nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo. %1-drive not mapped to %2
  echo. remapping %1
  subst %1 /D 1> nul
  subst %1 %2
) ELSE (
  echo. %1-drive already mapped to %2
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the output is the same here. I will need this as a subroutine callable with parameters P: and D:\mydir. How may I translate D:\mydir to D:\\mydir?

Comment: @ChrisJJ I edited my answer with a parameterized batch-file. It will add the double \ for you. You can use it like `remap p: d:\mydir`. (it's case insensitive now.) See the Edit in my answer.